# What is Red Five doing?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

During the end battle in space Red Five all of a sudden goes off on his own. I didn't really hear the commentary in the cinema at the time, so what is he doing?

I know the out of universe reason, so Luke can become Red Five, just wondering what the in universe reason is?

Comment: Dying is the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Film

In the film several of Red squadron seem to have panicked and broken formation. Both Red One and Red Five peeled off, earning an admonition from Red Leader.

> **Red Leader:** *Stick close to me. Red One, where are you going?*
>
> **Red One:** *They're all over me. I'm trying to lose them.*
>
> **Red Five:** *This is Red Five. I need help!* [he dies]

It's not really clear, but it's certainly possible that Red Five died because of the loss of cover from his squadron mates.

### Novelisation

The implication seems to be (at least according to the official novelisation) that Red Five, and indeed the remainder of Red Squadron were **intentionally making themselves targets in order to distract the gate's gunners from concentrating their fire on the Y-Wing bombers.**

> *A wing of Red Squadron fighters strafed the orbital gate station, maneuvering among clusters of sensor towers and laser turrets. The attack did little damage, but inflicting damage hadn’t been the goal—the fighters had claimed the station gunners’ attention, left a few turbolaser platforms in burning ruin, and given Gold Squadron’s Y-wings the opportunity for a bombing run.*

That's why Red Five's course was so erratic and dangerous and **ultimately what killed him.**

---

Comment: In the movie Red Five says he's trying to shake some TIE Fighters as Red Leader asks him what he's doing off on his own, and then he gets hit and dies.

Answer (score 5):

### Trying to destroy the shield

It seems that Red Five (a.k.a. Pedrin Gaul) was attempting to destroy the shield gate, along with most of Red Squadron:

> The death of individuals was no tragedy in battle. It was the death of
>   hundreds that would haunt him.
>
> He listened to cries of despair on the starfighters’ frequency and an
>   anguished scream as Red Five was torn apart. The Profundity’s shields
>   flashed constantly now. The chatter among the bridge crewmembers was
>   growing louder and more frantic.
>
> “We’re having no effect on the shield gate,” the lieutenant said. “And
>   we’re sustaining heavy losses, Admiral.”
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

In Red Squadron’s case, this was indirectly, by drawing attention away from the main bombers.

Comment: Ahem "*inflicting damage hadn't been the goal"* says the novel.

Comment: @Valorum - Indeed, but I thought it would be a bit impolite to edit that in after you put it in your answer. But OK.....

Comment: I've put a big header on mine so we can be big-header-buddies ;-)

Comment: @ Valorum - Yes.